# Creating Gin index for Postgres stored generated column in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I want to setup a Postgres ["stored generated columns"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS) with indexing to have full text search on two fields of a model. I created the generated column getting help from [this tutorial](https://pganalyze.com/blog/full-text-search-django-postgres), but when setting gin index on the column, I get this:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Article has no field named 'vector_column'. The app cache isn't ready yet, so if this is an auto-created related field, it won't be available yet.
```

Here's my `Article` model:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    content = models.TextField(...)
    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['vector_column'])]
```

and my custom sql in migration file:

```py
    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql='''
              ALTER TABLE articles_article ADD COLUMN vector_column tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title, '')), 'A') ||
                setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(content,'')), 'B')
              ) STORED;
            ''',

            reverse_sql='''
              ALTER TABLE articles_article DROP COLUMN vector_column;
            '''
        ),
    ]
```

Is it possible to set index from Django? Seems Django needs the field to be defined on the model but that's not how generated column works. If not, what's the correct way of setting the proper index (mentioned in this [Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX), the one at the end of the page) in migration files?

Comment: If you create a generated column manually via a migration you can't define the index in your model's Meta, the article only adds the index this way when using the SearchVectorField

Comment: @IainShelvington So then I should manually create the index in migration files?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way to add an index to the column since Django does not know about it

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. If you submit these commit along with samples for `sql` and `reverse_sql` parts, I would accept that as the answer.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak Yes. I'm past that stage and on the setting the Index up. I had no problem with searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Iain said in comments, index must be handled in migrations. I just added another migrations to `operations` array:

```py
    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql='''
              ALTER TABLE articles_article ADD COLUMN vector_column tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title, '')), 'A') ||
                setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(content,'')), 'B')
              ) STORED;
            ''',

            reverse_sql='''
              ALTER TABLE articles_article DROP COLUMN vector_column;
            '''
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql='''
                CREATE INDEX textsearch_idx ON articles_article USING GIN (vector_column);
            ''',

            reverse_sql='''
                DROP INDEX IF EXISTS textsearch_idx;
            '''
        ),
    ]
```